# Obtaining token from token service

Tags: iframe, ucwa

I am trying to obtain token for my UCWA app using passive auth. My setup is that once I receive the 401 challenge, I take the link to the token service from ms_rtc_passiveauthuri parameter and I visit this website (PassiveAuth.aspx) by creating a hidden iframe in the background of my website. Couple of redirects happen in that iframe but eventually I successfuly get the cookie and I proceed with creating the UCWA app.

This works nicely in IE, Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but Safari seems to refuse to do this redirections inside of that iframe.

I also tried to visit this token service by using the XFrame (and using helper library's Transport.clientRequest), but the result is 406 Not Acceptable.

Do you know about any workaround for Safari? Or, more importantly, is my approach correct - is this how it's meant to be used?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to work this out? I am having the same issues.

Edit : See the comments below for the answer - look out for the WWW-Authenticate and Www-Authenticate headers.

Comment: The problem for me was that in all browsers, one of the headers in the response is "WWW-Authenticate" whereas in Safari it is "Www-Authenticate", so you need to fix the boilerplate js files for safari.

Comment: You are a life saver, thank you. I would have spent hours trying to find that.

Comment: Heh, you're welcome :-). It took me few days to find it out myself.